# While accessing Web API getting 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

While accessing web Api in xamarin.forms i am getting this error below which is i am unable to Solve

> {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 12:50:00 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 1245 }}

This is my web Api Code.

```
public IList<TCourse> GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new HCMSEntities())
                {
                    var cli = (from b in context.tblTrainingCourses
                               orderby b.CourseID
                               select new TCourse { CourseID = b.CourseID, Course = b.Course }
                               ).ToList();

                    return cli;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And here is the code which is consuming the api and i am getting above error.

```
public async Task Index()
        {
            List<TCourse> EmpInfo = new List<TCourse>();

            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //Passing service base url  
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.20.2.62/");

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    //Define request data format  
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
                    HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/Course");

                    //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
                    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                        var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                        EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TCourse>>(EmpResponse);

                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
```

The web Api is not deployed.I tried http://localhost/ in  base address than i switched to Ip.
no idea whats wrong and where.
kindly Guide.

Comment: you url initialization is wrong where is the api function name GetData? try "api/Course/GetData

Comment: You mean i ll have to give my method name too??

Comment: yes then only it knows which method to call

Comment: I deployed api project and It worked!!
Thank God